# How to select checkboxes with certain names and check if at least one is checked with jquery?

Tags: jquery

If I have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="firstGroupOne">
<input type="checkbox" name="secondGroupOne">
<input type="checkbox" name="thirdGroupOne">
```

How can I select all checkboxes which end with `GroupOne` in the parameter `name` and also validate if at least one of these is checked? (As for the validation, I could iterate over each one and check, but maybe there is a one-liner with jquery?)

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name$="GroupOne"]:checked').length
```

This code will result in 0 if none are selected, or any number between 1 and 3 if 1-3 of them are selected.

**[Working jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/vrK24/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input:checkbox[name*=GroupOne]:checked").length
```

If length is greater than zero more than one is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/e78hH/

**EDIT**

Should ensure GroupOne only appears at end - example works in fiddle without quotes round 'GroupOne' -

```
$("#bt").click(function() {
    alert($("input:checkbox[name*=GroupOne]:checked").filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr('name').substring($(this).attr('name').length, $(this).attr('name').length - 8) == 'GroupOne'
    }).length)
});
```

The above is overkill - didn't know about '$=' selector! Every day's a school day! should be -

```
$("#bt").click(function() {
    alert($("input:checkbox[name$=GroupOne]:checked").length)
});
```

Comment: Close but won't work as you are missing the `""` around `GroupOne` will also detect GroupOne if it is in the middle of the name.

Comment: **That's not the way!!** you should use the `$=` selector. Correct your code and I'll remove the -1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Selecting them is as easy as:

```
$("input[name*="GroupOne"]:checked")
```

Then the validation... That kind of depends on what you want to do with them...

Comment: What if there's also a radio button?

Comment: @sl3dg3 `*=` is "contains". `^=` is "starting from". See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

hey thx for your inputs: with some fiddling I ended up with this, which is similar to your solutions:

```
if ( $(':checkbox[name$="GroupOne"]:checked').size() == 0 ) { // bad... }
```

Comment: Make sure to accept the correct answer to close this question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `:checked` selector in jquery .
More information at http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Yeah if u want ready to go solution it doesn't fit your criteria. But if u have brain to use `:checked` it's right. There are so lazy peoples... Regards.

Comment: The original question is to select **from a specific set of elements**, using `:checked` is the easy part.